# Algorithm for half-sample mode better than O(N^2)

Tags: time-complexity, dynamic-programming, statistics, online-algorithms

The **half-sample mode** is a mode estimator that homes in on the highest density region of a set of samples in search of the mode. It is one of the better mode estimators, though it fails for J-shaped and U-shaped distributions.

I coded an algorithm for the half-sample mode that may be O(N^2 log N) or possibly O(N log N log N), it is hard to tell, but for my test case it looks like the slower of the two. It uses triply-nested loops.

**What is N?** The input into traditional half-sample mode is a series of N samples which must be sorted before mode is performed. In my case, samples have been histogrammed into logarithmic buckets, so there are no duplicates and the sorted Map used internally yields the binned samples in sorted order. So for this algorithm, N is not the original number of samples, it is the number of distinct bins with non-zero counts, which can run to ten thousand or more. The weight is the count of samples in the bin.

- The outer loop cuts the target quantile range in half each iteration, so is log N.
- The second loop advances the start of a range of samples.
- The third and innermost loop advances the end of a range of samples to be evaluated.
- The subrange that is densest (narrowest range to equal or exceed the target quantile from the outer loop) is selected and its boundaries fed into the next iteration of the outer loop.

**Why is outer loop log N?** If every bucket only had a single sample (an extreme case) then the weight would be one for weach bucket. In that case, cutting the quantile width in half of the region of samples to process in each loop would be the same as dividing the number of samples in half. Since each iteration cuts the total weight in half, it shrinks N by half, hence is logarithmic. If some bins have larger weights than one, the reduction for some iterations could be either more or less than a half, but usually would eliminate more than one half of the samples, because a bin with a large weight is probably at or near the mode and that one bin will take up a large portion of the set preserved for the next iteration. Example: If a loop looks for the densest partition having at least a sum of weights of 20 and one bin has a weight of 10, then only 11 bins will be needed for the partition, not 20, meaning that things progress faster. So Log N is worst case.

Making the current approach faster looks like a fool's errand. This looks like a job for a dynamic programming approach. Any ideas? *Is there a **half-sample mode algorithm** out there that is better than quadratic in time complexity?* Since my application calls this function after every new sample is added, an algorithm that updates the mode incrementally and uses the previously estimated mode to speed computation would be good.

The rules of the algorithm are described here:

http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/h/hsmode.html

Some theory about this measure may be found here:

```
@article{Bickel2003RobustAE,
  title={Robust and efficient estimation of the mode of continuous data: the mode as a viable measure of central tendency},
  author={David R. Bickel},
  journal={Journal of Statistical Computation and Simulation},
  year={2003},
  volume={73},
  pages={899 - 912}
}
```

My implementation of the algorithm may be found in my open source Quantogram crate in `Rust`.

See https://github.com/paulchernoch/quantogram/blob/master/src/lib.rs

**Timings**. After extracting my code from its class, I wrote a test that adds a new value in each iteration then performs **hsm**. That means the test size is going up as a square of the number of iterations. However the execution time is going up as a cube of the number of iterations, so it is definitely worse than quadratic.

**Sample output**:

```
iterations = 125, time = 0.04 sec
iterations = 250, time = 0.16 sec
iterations = 500, time = 1.23 sec
iterations = 1000, time = 9.79 sec
iterations = 2000, time = 81.45 sec
iterations = 4000, time = 665.35 sec
```

**Pseudo Code**

Below, an interval defines a partition of the values between a low and high index and associated cumulative weight.

In the pseudo code, assume `interval > densest` overloads the
relational operator to compare the density of two interval objects.

- If two intervals have at least the desired cumulative weight (are not underweight), the denser interval is the one where the difference between the low and high values of the interval is smallest.
- If one interval is underweight, the other interval is considered densest.
- If both intervals are underweight, the one with the higher cumulative weight is denser.

```
1. samples = list of N sorted doubles
2. weights = list of N corresponding weights
3. wsum = sum(weights)
4. partition_weight = wsum / 2
5. bins = N
6. low = 0
7. high = N
6. densest = empty interval
7. while bins > 3  
8.    densest = empty interval
9.    for start in [low,high)
10.      interval = empty interval
11.      for index in [start,high)
12.         interval.add(index, samples[index], weights[index])
13.         if interval > densest
14.            densest = interval
15.         if interval.weight >= partition_width
16.            break
17.   low  = densest.start_index
18.   bins = densest.bins
19.   high = bins
20.   partition_weight = partition_weight / 2
21. mode = process cases for densest having 1,2, or 3 bins
```

**Code**.

Here is a working test of the algorithm in `Rust`.

```rust
use std::time::{Instant};

/// Internal structure for Half Sample Mode calculation.
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
struct HalfSampleInterval {
    /// Index of the first bin in rthe interval
    pub start_index: usize,

    /// Sample value for first bin.
    pub start_sample: f64,

    /// Count of the bins in the interval
    pub bins: usize,

    /// Sum of weights from all bins in the interval
    pub cume_weight: f64,

    /// Width of interval is the difference between the lowest bin sample value 
    /// and the highest bin sample value in the interval.
    pub width: f64
}

impl HalfSampleInterval {
    pub fn new(index: usize, sample: f64, weight: f64) -> Self {
        HalfSampleInterval {
            start_index: index,
            start_sample: sample,
            bins: 1,
            cume_weight: weight,
            width: 0.0
        }
    }

    pub fn empty() -> Self {
        HalfSampleInterval {
            start_index: 0,
            start_sample: 0.0,
            bins: 1,
            cume_weight: 0.0,
            width: 0.0
        }
    }

    pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.cume_weight == 0.0
    }

    pub fn add(&mut self, sample: f64, weight: f64) {
        self.bins += 1;
        self.cume_weight += weight;
        self.width = sample - self.start_sample;
    }

    pub fn is_underweight(&self, minimum_weight: f64) -> bool {
        self.cume_weight < minimum_weight
    }

    /// Check if this interval is denser than the other interval. 
    pub fn is_denser_than(&self, other: &Self, minimum_weight: f64) -> bool {
        if other.is_empty() && !self.is_empty() { true }
        else if self.is_underweight(minimum_weight) { false }
        else if other.is_underweight(minimum_weight) { true }
        else if self.width < other.width { true }
        else if self.width > other.width { false }
        else { self.cume_weight > other.cume_weight }
    }

}

pub fn hsm(samples: &Vec<f64>, weights: &Vec<f64>, total_weight: f64) -> Option<f64> {
    if total_weight == 0.0 { None }
    else {
        let count = samples.len();
        if count < 5 {
            let mut max_weight = 0.0;
            let mut samples_with_max_weight: Vec<f64> = Vec::new();
            for (&sample, &weight) in samples.iter().zip(weights) {
                if weight > max_weight {
                    max_weight = weight;
                    samples_with_max_weight = vec![sample];
                }
                else if weight == max_weight {
                    samples_with_max_weight.push(sample);
                }
            }
            return Some(samples_with_max_weight.iter().sum::<f64>() / samples_with_max_weight.len() as f64);
        } 
        let mut cume_target = total_weight / 2.0;
        let mut start_index = 0;
        let mut limit_index = samples.len();
        let mut densest = HalfSampleInterval::empty();
        while (limit_index - start_index) >= 2 { 
            densest = HalfSampleInterval::empty();
            for interval_start in start_index..limit_index {
                let mut current_interval = HalfSampleInterval::empty();
                for index in interval_start..limit_index {
                    if current_interval.is_empty() {
                        current_interval = HalfSampleInterval::new(index, samples[index], weights[index]);
                    }
                    else {
                        current_interval.add(samples[index], weights[index]);
                    }
                    if current_interval.is_denser_than(&densest, cume_target) {
                        densest = current_interval;
                    }
                    if !current_interval.is_underweight(cume_target) { 
                        break; 
                    }     
                }
            }
            start_index = densest.start_index;
            limit_index = start_index + densest.bins;
            cume_target = cume_target / 2.0;
        }
        match densest.bins {
            0 => None,
            1 => Some(samples[densest.start_index]),
            2 => {
                // TODO: Instead of taking the weighted average of two points, should we take the maximum?
                let i = densest.start_index;
                let weight_sum = weights[i] + weights[i+1];
                if weight_sum <= 0.0 {
                    None
                }
                else {
                    let weighted_mean = (samples[i] * weights[i] + samples[i+1] * weights[i+1]) / weight_sum;
                    Some(weighted_mean)
                }
            },
            3 => {
                // TODO: Instead of taking the weighted average of three points, should we take the maximum?
                let i = densest.start_index;
                let weight_sum = weights[i] + weights[i+1] + weights[i+2];
                if weight_sum <= 0.0 {
                    None
                }
                else {
                    let weighted_mean = (
                        samples[i] * weights[i] 
                      + samples[i+1] * weights[i+1]
                      + samples[i+2] * weights[i+2]) 
                      / weight_sum;
                    Some(weighted_mean)
                }
            },
            _ => None
        }
    }
}

pub fn simulate_convergence(iterations: usize) {
    let true_value = 100.0;
    let start_value = 0.0;
    let start_error = start_value - true_value;
    let mut values: Vec<f64> = Vec::new();
    let mut weights: Vec<f64> = Vec::new();
    let mut weight_sum = 0.0;
    for i in 1..=iterations {
        let error = start_error / (i as f64).sqrt();
        let next_value = true_value + error;
        // Must ensure values are sorted.
        values.push(next_value);
        weights.push(1.0);
        weight_sum += 1.0;
        let _mode = hsm(&values, &weights, weight_sum);
    }
}

fn main() {
  let test_sizes = vec![125,250,500,1000];
  for &size in test_sizes.iter() {
    let start_time = Instant::now();
    simulate_convergence(size);
    let duration  = start_time.elapsed();
    println!("iterations = {}, time = {:.2} sec", size, duration.as_secs_f64());      
  }

}
```

Comment: A naive implementation of the algorithm described in http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/h/hsmode.html runs in $\Theta(n)$ time if the input is a sorted array of $n$ $x$'s. But looking at your code, it looks like the problem is the **weighted** version. So, "N" is not the number of values, but the number of "bins" (can be thought of as a run-length encoded sequence).

Comment: Yes, I had to adapt to use weights, but my array of samples is assumed to be sorted.

Comment: You use $N$ in your question without defining it.  Please define what $N$ is.  You might also consider explaining why cutting the target quantile range in half each iteration means that the loop takes $O(\lg N)$ iterations (what's the relationship between $N$ and the number of possible values of the target quantile).

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained specification of the algorithm, as pseudocode, in the question?  We're not a coding site, and code is off-topic here.  Not everyone reads Rust.

Comment: I addedd definition of N and also justified why outer loop is Log N.

Comment: Added pseudo code as requested.